# RoR db:migrate not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using my local environment on Mac OS X with Rails 4.

When trying to run my migration, it is not running.

I receive the following output:

```
*******-C02MGBVJFD57:myapp *************$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
Your Gemfile lists the gem faker (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Your Gemfile lists the gem factory_girl_rails (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
== 20140815221246 AddPasswordDigestToUsers: migrating =========================
-- add_column(:users, :password_digest, :string)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'password_digest': ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `password_digest` varchar(255)/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `query'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `block in execute'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `execute'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:228:in `execute'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:375:in `add_column'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/Users/*************/workspace/myapp/db/migrate/20140815221246_add_password_digest_to_users.rb:3:in `change'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:595:in `exec_migration'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:992:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1040:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'password_digest': ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `password_digest` varchar(255)
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `query'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `block in execute'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `execute'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:228:in `execute'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:375:in `add_column'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/Users/*************/workspace/myapp/db/migrate/20140815221246_add_password_digest_to_users.rb:3:in `change'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:595:in `exec_migration'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:992:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1040:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'password_digest'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `query'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `block in execute'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `execute'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:228:in `execute'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:375:in `add_column'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/Users/*************/workspace/myapp/db/migrate/20140815221246_add_password_digest_to_users.rb:3:in `change'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:595:in `exec_migration'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:992:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1040:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/Users/*************/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any idea what is wrong?

EDIT:
The schema for the users table below:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
  end
```

Users Migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :password_digest, :string
  end
end

class AddRememberDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :remember_digest, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: This line in your logs states that the column already exists: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'password_digest': ALTER TABLE 'users' ADD 'password_digest' varchar(255)` - Look at your `db/schema.rb` file to see if the `password_digest` column already exists (a more robust check would be to directly examine the mysql database yourself).

Comment: So it looks like the users table is migrated fine, but running db:seed, I get:  You have 2 pending migrations:
  20140815221246 AddPasswordDigestToUsers
  20141114000137 AddRememberDigestToUsers
Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.

Comment: I added the schema portion, there is no duplicate of password_digest

Comment: Oh, you shouldn't manually modify the `db/schema.rb` file. The `db/schema.rb` file is suggesting that the `password_digest` column already exists in your db table. This means a previous migration added the column to the DB table, someone manually added the column to the DB table, or wasn't a migration wasn't properly rolled back. Could you post your migration files?

Comment: I just added the Users migration

Comment: Can you also post the `20140815221246 AddPasswordDigestToUsers` migration as well as `20141114000137 AddRememberDigestToUsers`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is happening because in your `CreateUsers` migration, you are already creating a `users` table with the `password_digest` column as evidenced by this line:

```
t.string :password_digest
```

Then, in your `AddPasswordDigestToUsers` migration, you're trying to add a column with the same name to the `users` table:

```
add_column :users, :password_digest, :string
```

This is where the migration failed with the error `Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'password_digest'`.

Are you sure you need the `AddPasswordDigestToUsers` file? It doesn't seem like it because you already added the column in the `CreateUsers` migration.

I think you can simply delete the `AddPasswordDigestToUsers` migration file and try re-running `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.